# What is the point of the super secret settings option in the video settings in minecraft 1.7?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was messing around with my settings in single creative mode, and I came across these really weird video settings, and I immediately thought what the heck!  They made the game hard, and it was almost impossible to tell between certain blocks.  It made no sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The super secret settings are a list of sounds and effects that may come out in future updates. You must turn all of the volume slides up inorder to hear them.

Answer (score 2):

Like many [easter eggs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Easter_egg_%28media%29), the Super Secret Settings are just a hidden feature of the game that plays a random sound or applies a random shader to the game. It wasn't made for any particular purpose, it's just there for fun and for what is colloquially referred to as "teh lulz."

If you want to turn them off, just restart your game.